# Parser skips lines

Tags: haskell, pug, parsec

I want to write a simple parser for a subset of [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/), generating some [XmlHtml](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmlhtml) for further processing.

The parser is quite simple, but as often with [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec), a bit long. Since I don't know if I am allowed to make such long code posts, I have the full working example [here](https://gist.github.com/2605850).

I've dabbled with Parsec before, but rarely successfully. Right now, I don't quite understand why it seems to swallow following lines. For example, the jade input of

```
.foo.bar
    | Foo
    | Bar
    | Baz
```

tested with `parseTest tag txt`, returns this:

```
Element {elementTag = "div", elementAttrs = [("class","foo bar")], elementChildren = [TextNode "Foo"]}
```

My parser seems to be able to deal with any kind of nesting, but never more than one line. What did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Parsec cannot match the remaining input, it will stop parsing at that point and simply ignore that input. Here, the problem is that after having parsed a tag, you don't consume the whitespace in the beginning of the line before the next tag, so Parsec cannot parse the remaining input and bails. (There might also be other issues, I can't test the code right now)

There are many ways of adding something that consumes the spaces, but I am not familiar with Jade so I cannot tell you which way is the "correct" way (I don't know how the indentation syntax works) but just adding `whiteSpace` somewhere at the end of `tag` should do it.

By the way, you should consider splitting up your parser into a Lexer and Parser. The Lexer produces a token stream like `[Ident "bind", OpenParen, Ident "tag", Equals, StringLiteral "longname", ..., Indentation 1, ...]` and the parser parses that token stream (Yes, Parsec can parse lists of anything). I think that it would make your job easier/less confusing.

Comment: Using the Token module is usually idiomatic for lexing with Parsec. However as Jade appears to use white-space significantly, I think you are right to suggest writing a separate scanner, see section 2.11 of the slightly out-of-date Parsec manual: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/daan/download/parsec/parsec.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately, I have added whitespace all around the `tag` and `tagP` parsers, and the result remains...

Comment: @Scán - that's a problem though. As Jade appears to be indentation sensitive so you can't use Parsec's `whiteSpace` or `lexeme` parsers directly as they consume all white-space. Indentation sensitive parsing is quite advanced (there are some libraries to help on Hackage - I don't know how useful or documented they are). If you are new-ish to Parsec / parsing I'd recommend choosing a language a that's bit simpler than Jade to get some practice on.

Comment: @stephentetley arguably since `whiteSpace` consumes white space up to a certain point, you'd still be able to get the parser column at that point and make it work. But I agree that the current parser isn't suited for this task.